# Login program in C

Tags: c

I'm new to programming. I'm trying to make a login program, where the user and the password are already stored in a ".txt" document, but no matter what the user's input is, it always shows "User or password incorrect!". Here is what I've done:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int sign_In(char user[30], char pass[30]){
    FILE *p;
    char user2[30], pass2[30];

    p= fopen("users.txt", "r");


    fscanf(p,"User: %s Password: %s",user2,pass2);

    if( (strcmp(user,user2)==0) && (strcmp(pass,pass2)==0) )
        printf("\nUser and password correct!!!");
    else
        printf("\nUser or password incorrect!\n\n");

    printf("\n\n");

    fclose(p);
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    char user[30], pass[30];

    printf("\nUser:");
    scanf("%s",user);
    printf("\nPassword:");
    scanf("%s",pass);

    sign_In(user, pass);

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not checking any of your inputs, so you don't know if the `fscanf()` in `sign_In()` reads anything, nor do you know whether your program successfully read the input from the user.  You should consider using `%29s` in place of the unconstrained `%s`.  You should definitely print the values being processed before you execute the `strcmp()` operations, so you can see what the program's testing compared with what you expect.

Comment: Try providing a representative example of the input (entered by the user) and the input file.   Also, check the values return by `fopen()`, `fscanf()`, etc - all of them can return values indicating errors have occurred.

Answer (score 2):

This code actually worked perfectly fine for me, so I will make the assumption that you probably have not created the `users.txt` file correctly.  Make sure it is in the format you set:

User: <kbd>Space</kbd> Chosen_Username <kbd>Space</kbd> Password: <kbd>Space</kbd> Chosen_Password

*Everything*, including spaces, should match your `fscanf` call as far as the format of the document goes.  When you are typing in your inputted username at the prompt, do not add an extra space or it might not match the format you have in your `fscanf` call.

Otherwise, the code worked perfectly.  As long as `users.txt` is in the correct format.

Comment: Note that the space in the format string corresponds to zero or more white space characters in the input file, except that the `%s` won't stop scanning until it encounters white space.  And the white space includes newlines.  The file could contain four lines, one with `User:`, one with the actual user name, one with `Password:` and another with the actual password — and `fscanf()` wouldn't notice.  It would also skip blank lines after the first (the first line must start with `User:`, but thereafter, blank lines are skipped).

Comment: Ah, maybe I am misunderstanding this issue, @JonathanLeffler.  Could the issue be that the asker has a `\n` at the end of the `users.txt` file?  Would `fscanf` continue to read that as well?

Comment: No; newlines count as white space.  They terminate the `%s`, and are skipped white space.

Comment: Ah, ok.  Thank you for the clarification.